# In Django - how do i use form validation in order to prevent two fields to be selected

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have 2 fields - fieldA, fieldB - and I want to prevent the user from submitting the form.

```
class IntroductionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         ...
def clean_fieldA(self):
    fieldA = self.cleaned_data.get('fieldA', True)
    fieldB = self.cleaned_data.get('fieldB', True)
    if not self.instance.fieldB == fieldB and not self.instance.fieldA == fieldA:
            raise ValidationError("You may not choose both fields")

    return fieldA
```

At this moment I can't choose fieldA at all without getting the validation error.
So how should it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the documentation says on [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). The right way to do it is to overwrite the `clean()` method, which gets called after the individual `clean_FIELD()`methods have been called.

```
class IntroductionForm(ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(IntroductionForm, self).clean()
        fieldA = bool(self.cleaned_data.get('fieldA'))
        fieldB = bool(self.cleaned_data.get('fieldB'))

        if fieldA and fieldB:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Can't select both forms")
        return cleaned_data
```

It is not entirely clear to if the user has to check one of the boxes. Then you would have to change the condition `fieldA and fieldB` to `fieldA != fieldB`. In this case, you could also consider using a radio box.

Comment: As you can see below... that exactly what I did :) Thanks anyway... this IS the correct answer

Comment: I should learn to type faster, you beat me to it by a few seconds ;) Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 1):

So this is the right solution (which works for me).
Because I need to validate two fields at the same time I use clean(self) and not a specific clean_fieldA(self) -  this way.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(IntroductionForm, self).clean()
    fieldA = cleaned_data.get('fieldA')
    fieldB = cleaned_data.get('fieldB')
    if fieldA and fieldB:
        raise ValidationError("You may not choose both fields!")

    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class IntroductionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         ...
def clean_fieldA(self):
    fieldA = self.cleaned_data['fieldA']
    fieldB = self.cleaned_data['fieldB']
    if self.instance.fieldB == fieldB and  self.instance.fieldB == fieldA:
            raise ValidationError("You may not choose both fields")

    return fieldA
```

Answer (score 0):

You first check the fields in the clean data and the check there values.

```
def clean_fieldA(self):

    if 'fieldA' in self.cleaned_data and 'fieldB' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['fieldA'] != self.cleaned_data['fieldB']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("You may not choose both fields."))

    return self.cleaned_data['fieldA']
```

Hope this will help you :)